# Display trix editor output

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

I am new to using the trix editor in AngularJS.  I have the editor in place and it is working correctly.  But I am not sure how to then display the content correctly.  I save the output of the trix editor but when I display it, its a string of html.

HTML:

```
  <trix-editor class="trix-content" ng-model="trix" angular-trix placeholder="Write something.."></trix-editor>
```

but when I try to display it somewhere else with this:

HTML:

```
<div class="trix-content">{{trix}}</div>
```

it just puts the raw string with html tags in it and is not showing just the text formatted.

ex)

```
<div> hello </div>
```

when I wanted

hello

Answer (score 1):

Angular has a directve for binding to rich text. Ex) `<div ng-bind-html='trix'></div>`

Comment: how to do this using HTML or vanilla JS?